# hg diff calling kdfif3 instead of outputting text

Tags: mercurial

Is it possible to run `kdiff3` instead of outputting text when I run `hg diff`? It can either be some switch or some setup that allows to hookup kdiff3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to pipe the git or Mercurial diff output to a GUI Diff tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954118/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-the-git-or-mercurial-diff-output-to-a-gui-diff-tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [extdiff extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension). That allows you to create new diff commands that can launch external diff tools, such as KDiff3.

You configure it with something like:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.vdiff = kdiff3
```

and you can then use `hg vdiff` to get a graphical diff using KDiff3. Strangely, the extension doesn't allow you to overload the normal `hg diff` command — it only lets you add new commands.